# How to select distinct values from a table

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I have a sql table which has the following entries.

```
Child_Name    Attempt_Number  Concept_ID   IsCompleted

 Class          NULL                C5         NULL

 Function       3                 C6           No

Function        4               C6           Yes
```

I want to get the result with the enties having distinct `child_Name` and maximum `attempt_Number`. The expected outcome is

```
Child_Name    Attempt_Number  Concept_ID   IsCompleted

Class           NULL                 C5         NULL

Function        4                C6            Yes
```

The entry of function with lower `attempt_Number` is removed..

Can anybody help?

Comment: So You need to types of entries 1) with NULL and 2) Max?

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `max()` function:

```
select * from yourTable where (child_name, attempt_number) in (
  select child_name, max(attempt_number) from yourTable group by child_name)
)
```

explanation: the inner table will give you the maximum attempt_number per child_name. since you want all columns and not only these two, you need the outer query to get them

Comment: Does MySQL support that "row an table constructor" syntax? (Also, you have an extra right parenthesis at the end.)

Answer (score 1):

You can try with -

```
select * from 
(select * from your_table order by attempt_Number DESC) tbl
group by child_name
```

Comment: he'd still get all results like that. he wants only one row per child/attempt

Comment: @NirLevy.. My bad.. Updated the answer.. Should work now.

Comment: after the edit you'll get one per row child but nothing guaranties it will be the highest

Comment: @Sougata This is working thanks a lot for your help.!

Comment: If it solved the issue please accept it as answer.. :)

Comment: That code seems a bit unpredictable. I wouldn't use it in code that's supposed to work with different (future) versions of MySQL (or other dbms products.)

Comment: This only works due to peculiarities of MySQL's GROUP BY "extension" and can be turned off. That "extension" allows MySQL to choose any values that relate to the columns in the group by, and there is NO control over how they get chosen. The assumption in this solution is that the subquery order will control it. I would not rely on this approach. see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Answer (score 1):

Use a sub-query to find each child's max Attempt_Number. Join with that sub-query:

```
select t1.Child_Name, t1.Attempt_Number, t1.Concept_ID, t1.IsCompleted
from tablename t1
  join (select Child_Name, max(Attempt_Number) as Max_Attempt_Number
        from tablename
        group by Child_Name) t2
    on t1.Child_Name = t2.Child_Name and t1.Attempt_Number = t2.Max_Attempt_Number
```

Will show both rows if there's a tie (same max in two rows for a child.)